# How to get tags and the date from tumblr posts using php?

Tags: php

I am rather new to PHP and I managed to get tumblr posts on my website. But only the title and the body.

1.) Why is it that I cannot grab the date?
2.) How do I go through all the tags and export them as well?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(-1);

$request_url = 'http://cedricfjacob.tumblr.com/api/read?type=post&start=0&num=10';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
$posts = $xml->xpath("/tumblr/posts/post"); 
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $title = $post->{'regular-title'};
    $post = $post->{'regular-body'};
    $tag = $post->{'tag'};
    $date = $post['date'];

    echo '<div class="title">'.$title.'</div>';
    echo '<div class="date">'.$date.'</div>';
    echo '<div class="tags">'.$tag.'</div>';
    echo '<div class="post">'.$post.'</div>';
}?>
```

In order to see the XML, please visit:

[https://cedricfjacob.tumblr.com/api/read?type=post&start=0&num=10#*=*](https://cedricfjacob.tumblr.com/api/read?type=post&start=0&num=10#_=_)

Thank you guys.

Comment: Please add the output of the api request. "var_dump($xml)";

Comment: Thanks @OfirBaruch I will keep that in mind for my next question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of two reasons:

1. With `$post = $post->{'regular-body'};` you **ovewrite** `$post` value. It is no longer what you expect.
2. Second - attribute `$post['date']` is a `SimpleXMLElement` object. To get string value of it - use `strval` for example or `(string)` typecasting.

In the end:

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $title = $post->{'regular-title'};
    $post_body = $post->{'regular-body'};    // change here
    $tag = $post->{'tag'};
    $date = strval($post['date']);           // change here

    echo '<div class="title">'.$title.'</div>';
    echo '<div class="date">'.$date.'</div>';
    echo '<div class="tags">'.$tag.'</div>';
    echo '<div class="post">'.$post_body.'</div>';  // change here
}
```

Comment: My god, I am embarrassed now! I looked at this for hours and did not see that I was reusing $post. Thanks!